# python3.6 import sqlite3 error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I installed Python3.6 on ubuntu16.04 and installed sqlite3.  When in python2, I can import sqlite successfully, but in python3 I got an import error.  I tried many methods from Google, but it still doesn't work.  I want to know how to solve it.

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Mar 13 2017, 06:38:19) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> import sqlite3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Comment: How exactly did you install Python 3?  How exactly did you install the SQLite module?

Comment: I compiled the source code to installed Pythhon 3。and installed sqlite with "sudo apt-get install sqlite3"

Comment: I recommend that instead of compiling the source yourself, you install it from a pre-built package.  Instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Comment: thanks, it's helpful

Answer (score 4):

`sqlite3` will comes with python itself. I also get the same problem i just uninstalled the `python3.6` and installed again.

uninstall existing python:

```bash
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6
```

Install python3.6:

```bash
sudo apt install -y \
  build-essential \
  checkinstall

sudo apt install -y \
  libreadline-gplv2-dev \
  libncursesw5-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  libsqlite3-dev \
  tk-dev \
  libgdbm-dev \
  libc6-dev \
  libbz2-dev

PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.0

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz
tar xvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz
cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}/
./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

It works!

Answer (score 3):

You can install python3 and sqlite by yourself.
[try this.](https://www.bluebill.net/2016/04/24/install-python-and-sqlite-from-source/)

Or you can try it as follows,

```
1. install sqlite3
$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-autoconf-3170000.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
$ tar zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3170000.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3170000
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sqlite3 --disable-static --enable-fts5 --enable-json1 CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1"

2. install python3.6
$ cd Python-3.6.0 
$ LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/sqlite3/lib ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.6 LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/sqlite3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/local/sqlite3/include"
$ LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/sqlite3/lib make
$ LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/sqlite3/lib make install
```

Comment: thanks, I installed python3.6 and sqlite as below, but it still dosen't work。and then i found python3.5 on ubuntu16.04，which can import sqlite3 successful

Comment: If python3.5 works well, I think you can copy the *.so file directly to the location of python3.6.

Comment: you can try python3.5 for sqlite . The only ption i found.